# Unable to perform blob detection on background subtracted video opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a video which was obtained by performing background subtraction on another video. Now I need to perform blob detection on this video and mark the blobs with a red border. My code is as follows:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('bw.avi')
size = (int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('harsha_blob.avi', fourcc, 10.0,size)

while (1):
    ret, im = capture.read()
    im = cv2.convertScaleAbs(im)

    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.blobColor = 0
    params.filterByColor = True
    params.minArea = 0
    params.filterByArea = False
    params.minThreshold = 120;
    params.maxThreshold = 255;
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

    keypoints = detector.detect(im)

    # Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    # cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)


    if ret==True:

        video.write(im_with_keypoints)


    else:
        capture.release()
        video.release()
        break

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The background subtracted video was inverted to make the blobs black and the background white as blob detection finds black/grey blobs. I am able to detect the blobs in a single frame but I am getting the following error when I try to run it on the video.

```
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\features2d\src\draw.cpp:115: error: (-215) !outImage.empty() in function cv::drawKeypoints
```

Why am I getting the error? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!outImage.empty()` happens at the end of the video, when there are no more frames and `ret, im = capture.read()` returns `ret==False`. You should check that condition before you find the keypoints for the blobs.

```
while (1):
    ret, im = capture.read()
    if not ret: 
        break

    # blob detection code
```